# how to do something before setting a public attribute of the object?

Tags: php, class, oop

If I get a class looks like this :

```
class a {
    public $aa;
    public $ab;
}
$t = new a();
```

now, 
If I type `$t->`, I would got a tip list under zend Studio, but now I need to do something like this:

```
class a {
    public $aa;
    public $ab;
    public function __get( $name ){
        $this->$name = x;
        return $this->$name;
    }
}
```

so, what should I do? First I still want to get that tip list, and only public attribute could be listed. and idea about this?

Comment: Since $name can be anything, Zend Studio cannot really suggest all possibilities... Plus, I would really suggest you declare all your properties in the top of your class like for $aa and $ab. And maybe use a mechanic more like $this->myVars[$name] instead.

Comment: Also Zend Studio will put all private protected and public properties in the code suggestion list.

Comment: Use getters, not magic methods. Magic methods are virtually impossible to actually type hint by definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me, that you're having two interlocking problems here.

If you add public fields to your class, then you can see them in autocomplete suggestions and it is easier for you to write code, but if you do that, then __get is not executed because this is a visible property and __get is only called for the invisible properties.

If you remove the public fields (or make them private so as to make them invisible), then your __get is executed but you don't get any autocomplete suggestions as there are no visible fields. This way your code works, but it is harder for you to write the code as you get no autocomplete suggestions.

So my suggestion to you would be to forget the __get functionality altogether. Pretend that it does not exist (since it does not do what you want it to do anyway). Use member functions instead of public properties and you'll get the autocomplete suggestions as well as your code executed. Yes you'll have to implement more methods that way, but that's life, you can't always have everything you want, you have to compromise.

What you can do is use something from the Java book and define methods for getters and setters (so either `function getName()` and `function setName($value)` or if you prefer you can use `function name($value = null)` and either set or get depending on the passed in value) or you can assign those values in a constructor if you don't care about the laziness part and the only thing you'll do is assign values.

Comment: Thank you 4 your anser, but I'm sorry, I may not make you understand it clearly, I mean, If I let __get() works, I can not public all attributes, then I can not get the tip list. so, now, the problem is, I need the tip list and also need __get() method works. I read the phpdoc manual, and did not find any thing but it...., so I think, If I could let __get() works and public all attributes, then it's good. any suggestion?

Comment: @MichealLuthor, I've added more elaborations to my answer to make myself more clear. Hope that helps, tell me if you think I misunderstood you completely

Comment: thank you so much 4 your answer, I think function name($value = null) is best for me, cause it's clear and easier.  Anyway, Thank you again.

Comment: Glad to be of assistance. :)